# How to recover override codes in VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have written some codes in VS code. However, after I changed the code slightly, the editor asked me to override the file. Not to my notice, the has became a much older version so I clicked override. The file has now been saved. How can I recover to the last version? I have rewritten the code for too long,